# Deleting a row from all the tables in a schema

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a schema, named BILL, and in this schema all the tables have a column named ID. I need a way to delete the row from all the tables, where ID = 'test'. There are a lot of schemas, so it is important that i only delete them from BILL. There are tables that don't contain a test row too if it matters. This is an oracle database.

I couldn't figure out how to do this with sql. Maybe pl/sql? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with `execute immediate`:

```
begin
   for t in (select table_name from dba_tables where owner = 'BILL') loop

       execute immediate 'delete from ' || t.table_name || 
                         ' where id = ''test''';

   end loop;
end;
/
```

This should work if *all* tables in that schema have a column name named `id` (as you indiciated is the case). Otherwise, you should join with `dba_tab_columns` to make sure to only select tables that have such a column.

It will fail, too, if `id` is a primary key that other tables reference. In that case you could embed the `execute immediate` into a

```
begin
  execute immediate '....';
exception when others then
  dbms_output.put_line('failed to delete in ' || t.table_name);
end;
```

Comment: All the tables have an ID column and all the IDs are primary keys that other tables use as foreign key. But there are no data that actually refers to the 'test' rows. I see the logic in your sql but it fails with an error when I execute.

Comment: [BEGIN - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 6550, SQL State: 65000]  ORA-06550: line 5, column 53:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem return
   returning <egy kitevő (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or
   like LIKE2_ LIKE4_ LIKEC_ between into using || bulk member
   SUBMULTISET_

Comment: You can actually run only the `select` part and manually run the generated query. In that case you can modify the query before it is run

Comment: This is a syntax error.  Most likely you have missed out a space in your boilerplate text, or a quote mark or something.